# Why is my cake join throwing in a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: cakephp, join

I’m working on a join for two HABTM relationships.

I have a table named projects and it has a HABTM relationship with the users table.  It uses the intermediary table projects_users, for its HABTM relationship.

Then the users table has a HABTM relationship with departments (using the department_users table).
Here is my join statement (which is in my projects_controller):

```
$projectsUsersDepartments['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'users',
        'alias' => 'User',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.id = ProjectsUser.user_id'
        )
    ),
    array('table' => 'departments_users',
        'alias' => 'DepartmentsUser',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'DepartmentsUser.user_id = User.id'
        )
    )
);

$projectsUsersDepartments['conditions'] = array(
    'ProjectsUser.project_id' => 1,
    'DepartmentsUser.department_id' => 25
);

$projectsUsers = $this->Project->ProjectsUser->find('all', $projectsUsersDepartments);
```

Here is the SQL it’s producing:

```
SELECT `ProjectsUser`.`id`, `ProjectsUser`.`user_id`, `ProjectsUser`.`project_id`, `ProjectsUser`.`status`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`contractor_id`, `User`.`group_id`, `User`.`title`, `User`.`last_name`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`main_phone`, `User`.`cell_phone`, `User`.`fax`, `User`.`address`, `User`.`city`, `User`.`state`, `User`.`zipcode`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`is_active`, `User`.`is_verified`, `User`.`is_id_verified`, `User`.`last_login`, `User`.`last_password_change`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` 
FROM `projects_users` AS `ProjectsUser` 
inner JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`User`.`id` = `ProjectsUser`.`user_id`) 
inner JOIN `departments_users` AS `DepartmentsUser` ON (`DepartmentsUser`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`ProjectsUser`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)  
WHERE `ProjectsUser`.`project_id` = 1 AND `DepartmentsUser`.`department_id` = 25
```

I cannot understand why the join is throwing in the line:

```
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`ProjectsUser`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)
```

It’s causing a `SQL Error: 1066: Not unique table/alias: 'User'`  error, because User is being defined twice.

I don’t see how I’m telling the join statement to do that.  Is there something I’m missing  in my understanding of cake joins?  Thanks!

Comment: Does your ProjectsUser model belongsTo User? Try setting your `recursive` to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's considered good practice to set `public $recursive = -1;` in your AppModel - that way, your finds won't automatically add stuff without your knowledge.

"Recursive" is a nice idea, but should never really be used in practice, which is why it's been completely removed in Cake 3.

**In this case, recursive being greater than -1 is likely your problem.**

Comment: In the line before my join I have `$this->Channel->recursive = -1;`.  But you say I should set it in my AppModel?  Could you give me an example of how to do that?

Comment: Copy the code from the first line of my answer, and pasted it into your AppModel class.  But it sounds like that's not the answer to this question after all.

Comment: True.  I did that and the error is gone now; but in debug it doesn't display all the fields I hoped it would.

Comment: I take that back, it is working!  It's another part of my code that's giving an error now.  I'm on to the next one, yeah!  Thanks for the help, Dave!